# Is there a way to show a password while you type it in a textbox in mvc5

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-5

i want to have be able to view my password as  i type it is there a way to do that in mvcc5

Comment: Chnage `type="text"` to view password.. or  you might be looking for this http://cloudfour.github.io/hideShowPassword/

Comment: Use a text input instead of a password input?

Comment: You might be interested in [this artice](https://css-tricks.com/better-password-inputs-iphone-style/)

Answer (score 0):

Its pure HTML there. If you use

```
<input type="password">
```

the browser will automatically hide what you're typing. If you want to be able to see what is being typed, you chould change to

```
<input type="text">
```

If you're using Razor, its probably just changing from @Html.Password or @Html.PasswordFor to @Html.TextBoxor @Html.TextBoxFor